What to do when managment interrupts a meeting and puts you down infront of everyone
I have the following situation. I am techlead of a team developing and maintaining platform for data exchange in and out of the organization. I am also a consultant. I have a team lead and I also have a product lead . There is another team that is pushing for adoption of competing technology to what we are developing and maintaining but instead of being developed in our organization it is developed outside and if we start using it we will use some pary of the value chain and outsource it. There are also considerations about security, extensability, robustness how easy it is to make a change and so on.
We had a meeting the two teams plus an architect that sits very high in the hierarchy of the organization. I had prepared a comparison analysis in advance between the two solutions and this comparison analysis was very detailed and technical and was pointing to what are the weaknessess in the other solution and it was relativly clear I was recommending that the work is not outsourced out of the organization. First spoke the other team. Then it was our turn, I spoke around 30 min and whent to roughly 50% of what I was to present  (it was a 3 hours meeting one day plus 3 hours the other day) when I was very brutaly interrupted by this architect. He was stating that they have a commyunication problem, that I am not communicating athe right level. I should be more talking about business and not about technicalities and alls sorts of things basiclty he interrupted the whole presentation and did not agree for us to continue. As I said we had scheduled 3 hours + 3 hours workshop so the second 3 hours session was removed from the calendar and we agreed that we will meet again after the summer where instead of going into details we need to see fewature by feature pros and cons. Which is a very simplistic way of aproaching this case in my opinion. It seems they dont have a technical case so they are shying away from the technicalities.
My problem. 1) This guys apears to be relativly high in the hierarchy, but I dont report directly to him I report to my Product lead who is also holding my contract.

I was expecting some sort of clear guidelines from my product lead with regards of this meating. I did not get any so I put in the report what I think.
I did not expect so violent reaction from the other parties involved to my analysis which most probably mean I have stept on the wrong foot of somene pushing for something.

I am still the tech lead of one of this two teams. What is the best strategy here to get out both with dignity and with my job / contract intact because I have the feeling that after so violent reaction the next step can be to remove the problem / remove the person. I have not recieved any clear indication from my product lead on what to do.
I am considering either to step down as Tech lead , or alternativly to try to avoid the meeting and put someone else possibly more agreeable than me on the line. How should I arpoach this case ?

You were given two GREAT answers. To add to them. ROI - Return on investment. As a tech person, you might not think in those terms. Businesses MUST. It is clear to you why to not use tech with security holes in it. But if you don't explain that the ongoing support costs and RISK to the company in a reasonably quantifiable way, then you are just spewing techno-babble. You can be 100% right, But if you can't "Elevator Pitch" why, then you've lost. It isn't fair, but it is business. Don't quit, learn to talk business. 1.) Does it increase Sales, 2. Does it lower costs, 3. Does it lower Risk.

Were you told who the ‘audience’ was for the meeting?  Was it intended to persuade the higher-up, or to inform the other team?  Those are very different targets, and it seems your understanding of the meeting's goal was very different from the higher-up's.  (If you can ascertain it for the follow-up meeting, and focus your presentation accordingly, then it's likely to go better.)

Short summary - please correct me if I'm wrong:

Two parties brought their arguments to the table.

You were interrupted by someone higher in the food-chain who seems to be a big stake-holder.

This person reminded you that you are not communicating at the right level.


I would wait for the follow-up meeting after the summer. Don't care too much about it - such situations as you described happen all the time within a company or between groups of different interests.
Next time ask for a detailed guideline from your superior on how to do your analysis and what points to bring to attention when presenting said analysis.
Stepping down as a tech lead seems a bit drastic and avoiding the follow-up meeting might give your superiors the impression that you are not living up to the expectations of being in a lead position and that you try to avoid confontation (which are/can be part of leading positions).
Maybe speak to your superior about their thoughts on how this went down and ask for future guidelines in similar regards. Otherwise just brush it off and don't let it get to you - these situations are not that uncommon.

From OPs writing it seems he gave a very detailed, technical presentation. This is useful to have but might not be what the high level stakeholders wants to hear. They probably want someone to do this (for example OP) and then give him the executive summary with the major points.

It sounds like this is a great opportunity for a learning experience in how to convert technical issues to business cost, and how to present that to a less technical manager. The fact that they haven't already removed you as tech lead means this meeting was not as big of a disaster as you seem to think it was, and I would definitely not voluntarily step down - seems like a great way to lose your contract to me.I would suggest coming up with a plan for how to present your case at the next meeting, and then running it by your direct manager. This presentation should include a base level of what technical issues are expected to arise with the competing project, but not with any level of detail. The detail should lie in the more business side of the summary.  Eg "Because of decreased security features, we will need to stand up our own systems. This will require at least X months of delay before launch, with risks of it taking up to Y months." Something along those lines. Also, you said the other team presented first in this meeting so you should already have an idea of what information to include based off of what they said.

I like iLuvLogix answer, but will provide some additional detail:

I don't think you were insulted.  People higher up on the management chain are looking for generalities and how your solution will change the profit and loss statement.  They don't care about a rich, bug free API but they do care if it means it will be a faster implementation.  It is your responsibility to know that.

Perhaps watching some videos on how to talk to upper management are in order here.

Expecting clear guidelines is silly.  Why? Because many times people don't know enough to provide the information themselves.  It is your responsibility to know your audience and give the appropriate information in the presentation.  A prior visit to the Architect's office, asking the level of detail they were looking for would have been a good idea.

Stepping down as tech lead will destroy your reputation with this company.  It is basically saying "I am a cry baby", or at the least "I can't handle a moderate amount of pressure".


People who move up in management tend not to be the most agreeable people.  A lot of people want the big office and being able to tell people what to do, and the salary as well.
They can be a bit callous at times.

+1 for the start of the answer.  The last two paragraphs do not match my experience at all however.  I'd agree that senior managers tend to be busy and may be brusque but have not come across any company that routinely promoted unpleasant people.

@OmarandLorraine TY, my spelling is terrible.  Corrected.
