How to manage talkover in meetings?
I was in a management meeting. There was a high stake person for which my team has done a project in past.
I was the supervisor / project manager for that project, and project was done by this other team member - member B.
During meeting, this high stake person asked me a non-technical question related to that project seeking my recommendations.
I just uttered a one word, and suddenly, my senior interrupted and told in front of everyone present in that meeting that this project was done by member B, who was also present in meeting, and that this member-B will answer the question.
Now, this other person - member B, ended up explaining just technical detail, and not the right answer.
I have experienced such thing for the first time. I am bit confused about this situation.
Should I ignore it, or should I take any necessary actions, such as:

Share right answers with stake holder
Ask my senior why he interrupted me
Discuss and Coach my team member


"Ask my senior why he intruppted me": start with that. Keep your emptions out of it and just try to learn what your senior expected you to do )or not to do) and why.

slightly related:  https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/198292/what-to-do-when-managment-interrupts-a-meeting-and-puts-you-down-infront-of-ever

You do not say if the client was happy or not after the explanation.  This is very important.

Did it matter for the outcome of the meeting? The product? Your career? Your wellbeing? To me it just sounds like hurt pride.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine.. The client was neutral as he didn't get the right answer.

@Michael, could you please help me to understand how this lead to hurt pride. Secondly , was this a fair treatment?

Be careful you are not reading more into a neutral result than is fair.  If the client felt they "didn't get the right answer", they'd be more negative in body language or verbally.  It sounds like you didn't like the answer, rather than that anyone else had a problem with it.  This does sound more like a bruised ego than an issue to dwell on.

Discuss and coach your senior!

What do you mean with "my senior", do you mean your manager or superior, or a senior engineer (or other type of senior) in the project team?

Perhaps this senior can resolve your understanding of the circumstances by discussing the issues involved and coaching you.

This happened to me a lot. Do not ignore it. You can turn it to your advantage.
What you can in such a situation is:

Begin with: "let me add a little detail on Team Member's correct answer"
Veeery briefly repeat and summarize the team member's answer
Add the non-technical part of the answer
Later on, ask your senior why he interrupted you. At this point you might receive an answer or maybe not.
You can start coaching your team member on the difference between the various type of answers (technical vs. non-technical)


Exactly this, +1. It's very important the first step: provide all the relevant information while not contradicting your team mate answer. Your boss will recognise that they made a mistake in interrupting you and won't probably do it again

Thank you for the answer. Next, time I will try to follow this strategy.

This is risky. See the other answer for a much safer approach.

Good answer to the question as posed; here it's bad advice because this seems very strongly to be an X/Y problem.

This is very good advice provided you first make eye contact with your boss. You can avoid the situation  illustrated in @Heinzis answer with a little non verbal communication.

If your boss signals you to stop talking during a meeting with a client, you stop talking.

Let me elaborate on that. There are two possible explanations for what happened:

Your senior was mistaken in redirecting the question to team member B, or

your senior knew what you were about to say and did not want that to be said in front of the client.


Trying to find out during the meeting whether option 1 or 2 is correct is very hard and requires both careful phrasing and a certain level of familiarity between you and your senior. The safe option is to keep your mouth shut.
After the meeting, you can talk to your senior in private, tell them what you would have liked to add, and ask them whether it makes sense to give that information to the client (for example, by mail or a follow-up phone call).

I agree in most cases with your first sequence and definitely when you are already talking and the boss interrupts you. However, as described in the OP, this is definitely case 1. So maybe, if we want to be extra safe, OP could insta-message boss saying: "it's ok if I add X to B's answer?" and move from there. OP being quiet could miss an opportunity to show clearly that they are the expert and that they can bring value to discussion. What if the OP's bit makes the difference between winning or losing the client?

This is the correct answer. I've been the boss and I rarely interrupted a team member during meetings, especially with outsiders, but whenever I did it, I did it very intentionally and mostly to shut them up before they say something they shouldn't say.

@nicola: "However, as described in the OP, this is definitely case 1." OP might be sure it's case 1, but the boss might know stuff that OP doesn't. It's a judgment call, but, personally, I'd err on the side of safety and talk it over in private afterwards. If it was benign, it at least shows the boss that his interruptions are taken seriously and maybe stops him from interrupting (without a good reason) next time.

In my case the boss knew that I am the expert in this topic. This is why I was confused with the behavior.  Secondly, my boss also knew that in such scenario where others members are also involved, I always ensure the views of other team member are also acknowledged.

@Heinzi Your POV is certainly reasonable, but I'd like to add a point: bosses are not always right. And strictly obeying is not always the right thing to do. The best companies are made of people who exceed boss' expectations. Strict compliance with no exception might please the boss, but it's probably not the best route for your own career.

@nicola: There's a big difference between internal & external meeting. If my boss is wrong in a team meeting, or a meeting with a close-by team, I'll politely signal I believe they're mistaken. If my boss is wrong with a distant team or an external party, I'll make a note and check with them later, because regardless whether he's wrong or I am, you don't want a lengthy debate to sprout between the two of you right here and right there. At least, not unless there are lives at stake.

@Mike: This is not about you being an expert, or even about you being wrong or right. It's about a (correct) information that your boss might not want to be revealed to the client for (whatever) reasons you don't know about.

@nicola: I fully agree, and I'd always want my employees to tell me if I'm wrong. However, "in front of the client" is often not the right place for that. :-)

@Heinzi There is a place also to intervene, if there are robust reasons, during client meetings. I can remember a few occasions in which spontaneous interventions from  my team made the difference between winning and losing a client (yes, of course there are cases in which we lost because of that). Your first sentence, IMO, is way too definitive and it reads like a rule with no exception, which I think is not.

@Mike Another option you perhaps haven't considered is that your senior is mentoring the other team member (B). In addition, if I was your senior and B was leading the project, I'd have done the same to ensure that the client contacts B as the first port of call, and if B wants to invite you to answer as the subject expert then that's fine, but they're the account/project manager and thus they are the one to make that call. This may also be your senior protecting you from being dragged in more than necessary by the client. Only way to know is to ask your senior!

I actually don't see that it's "definitely case 1."
OP might believe that it's definitely case 1. That doesn't mean that that's actually the case, or that's what case the superior thought it was.
OP: Ask the superior, to the side, during break. Hopefully you'll either learn something, or get an apology.

I wouldn't say that this is necessarily the correct answer, because if there is someone from your company who has no idea what things to say in front of the customer, or who's input is not needed/valued they shouldn't be in the meeting to begin with. Now of course some unpredictable situation could arise in the middle of the meeting, but if you are the one in charge to handle the customer relation, you should already have a clear idea of what you can and cannot promise them.
